# Can't print correctly the size of a mongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pymongo

I'm currently trying to print the content of a mongo query by casting it to a list and then trying to access to the length of that list, I'm using the following code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
from pprint import pprint


client = MongoClient('...')
db_profile = client['...-profiles']

collection_profile = db_profile['profiles']

# print(collection_profile.count())

querydate = datetime(2020, 1, 1)
year = querydate.year
month = querydate.month
yesterday = querydate.day
dateStr = str(year) + "-" + str(month) + "-" + str(yesterday)
date = parse(dateStr)

result = collection_profile.find({'createdAt': {'$gte': date}})
pprint(list(result)) # Here I got the data correctly
print(len(list(result))) # Here I got 0 as result
```

If I switch the position of the last 2 lines, I got the correct size, but then an empty list.
What could be wrong? Is there a better method to access to the content of a query using `pymongo`?

Answer (score 2):

Because the find function is an iterator, you can only go through it once.  After your first `pprint(list(result))` the `result` iterator has reached the end of the query. From then on it won't return any more data.

You would need to store the first list conversion in a variable in order to access the content again:

```
resultList = list(result)
pprint(resultList)     # will use list that is now in memory
print(len(resultList)) # this will work
```

If you have a very large result set, this may cause a memory overflow or performance degradation.  Mongo can return the count using the collection's count() function to which you can pass the same query object.